# Triggering https request from mongoDB whenever any documnet is updated/inserted

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x

I want to trigger http request from mongoDB to python whenever any documnet is updated/inserted in mongoDB. I am pretty new to it. I dont know if it can be done using **REST**(eve) or there is some mechanism in mongoDB which can help me with it. Can any one please guide me? If it can be done through **REST** then how can I do it?